# Struggling to initialize with initial state and connect

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to initialize a reducer with some initial state and connect it to a component and have not been able to resolve why my state is always null in my component.

I'm including a link to codesandbox.io that has different permutations commented out in the reducer.

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-hypatia-dr9c1

Reducer after tinkering to try to make sure it would at least work (original is commented out in project):

```
var abilityStats = {
  strength: 18,
  dexterity: 12,
  constitution: 12,
  intelligence: 12,
  wisdom: 12,
  charisma: 13
 };

const abilityStatsReducer = (state = abilityStats, action) => {
  var stats = {}
  if(abilityStats) {
    stats.strength = {
      score: stats.strength,
      mod: calculateAbilityMod(stats.strength)
    };
    stats.dexterity = {
      score: stats.dexterity,
      mod: calculateAbilityMod(stats.dexterity)
    };
    stats.constitution = {
      score: stats.constitution,
      mod: calculateAbilityMod(stats.constitution)
    };
   stats.intelligence = {
     score: stats.intelligence,
     mod: calculateAbilityMod(stats.intelligence)
   };
   stats.wisdom = {
     score: stats.wisdom,
     mod: calculateAbilityMod(stats.wisdom)
   };
   stats.charisma = {
     score: stats.charisma,
     mod: calculateAbilityMod(stats.charisma)
   };

    return stats
  }

  return state
};
```

Root reducer:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  abilityStats: abilityStatsReducer()
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Component I am trying to access the state in:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class AbilityStats extends Component {
  // constructor(props) {

  //   super(props);
  //   var strength = props.abilityStats
  //   debugger;

  // }

  state = this.props.abilityStats;

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.strength.score}</div>
        <div>test</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { abilityStats } = state;
  return {
    ...abilityStats
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AbilityStats);
```

I get the error messages

> Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.

and

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'strength' of null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a function to `combineRedudcer` instead of calling it.

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  abilityStats: abilityStatsReducer()
});
```

This should be

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  abilityStats: abilityStatsReducer
});
```

In your `mapStateToProps` you need to return `abilityStats` instead of returning destructuring of it.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { abilityStats } = state;
  return {
    abilityStats
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You you doing wrong in `mapStateToProps`, do this

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return state;
};
```

Also while accessing state, you can directly use as,

```
{this.props.strength}
```

Also you made a mistake in `combineReducers`,

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  abilityStats: abilityStatsReducer // `()` not needed here
});
```

**Note:** As you have only one reducer, you can directly use reducer without `combineReducers`,

You can directly export your reducer,

```
export default abilityStatsReducer
```